# Accept suggested edit that's already been rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

This edit to my answer is correct but was unanimously rejected by three (mistaken) reviewers:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5149865 .

How can I accept the edit?

Answer (score 11):

Make the edit yourself.

Comment: Then the edit-suggestor doesn't get credit for it, though.

Comment: The edit suggestor only gets credit for edits that you can approve before the community declines them.

Comment: Well that's dumb.  Why bother giving out credit for finding subtle mistakes like this if it's just a popularity contest?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that.  Suggested editors are not supposed to change the meaning of a post, and this suggested edit clearly does.

Comment: Huuh?  Aren't you supposed to edit almost-right answers "To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages"? (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Prose, yes.  Not code.  Notice that the post you linked never mentions editing of code.

Comment: Doesn't say that in the help centre page I linked.  (And it also doesn't limit its scope to prose.)  I'll just leave the bug be if that's what you all are after.

Comment: Now you're just being stupid.  It's *your code.*  Fix it yourself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what to do with almost-right answers where the poster is long gone? Downvoting for a typo is a bit unfair.

Comment: Well, no; SE has the perpetual and irrevocable right to create derivative works of it.  Now your process failed and you seem to be making up rules that don't exist to justify it.  Seems like the proper thing to do is to ding the users who reviewed the edit incorrectly, let the edit go through, and move on.

Comment: @JanDvorak: In the edit description: *"This poster is long gone, and their code doesn't work, so I'm fixing it myself."*

Comment: To back-up Robert: [User suggested great corrective edit to my answer, but the edit was rejected. What can I do to approve it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135967/user-suggested-great-corrective-edit-to-my-answer-but-the-edit-was-rejected-wh) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question)

Comment: @tmyklebu: There's nothing in the system that provides for that, sorry.  And the reviewers are merely following the community gestalt.

Comment: @RobertHarvey can't we teach them?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Teach who what?  Folks, all a suggested editor needs to do is earn 2000 rep, and they can make these kinds of edits without community approval, if they so choose.

Answer (score 6):

Once it was reviewed, you can't review it anymore, accept or reject it. Make an edit yourself.